# Preventing users from deleting a row in a particular table with a certain value in a particular column in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

This may be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769653/prevent-user-from-deleting-certain-rows-based-on-contents-of-a-cell-in-that-row) but I believe it goes a step further in complexity which is why I asked it.

**Context:** I'm building a budget spreadsheet that can create and delete rows from tables. In the sheet I have two tables. One contains totals based on category, while the other table contains the transactions the user can enter in to populate the totals in the other table. I protected the worksheet to keep users from breaking the formulas and only have the cells they should edit (i.e. input values in) unprotected. I also have macros to insert and delete one or multiple rows on a table (I coded the macros to unprotect/protect the worksheet before and after the macro is finished running).

**Problem:** My question deals with the [first table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IzRH.png). In that table, I want to ensure that the "Deposits" row cannot be deleted. Question is, in my code, how can I ensure the user can delete all other rows in another table that contains "Deposits" while preventing deletion of the "Deposits" row in this table? I'm thinking of the following pseudo code, but feel free to make other suggestions:

```
'If selected range contains cells in Column A
'and cell in selected range = Deposits
'Then pop error message
'Exit Sub
```

And here is the code I have for my delete macro

```
Sub DeleteRow()
'
' DeleteRow Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+D
'

Dim loTtest         As ListObject
Dim loSet           As ListObject
Dim c               As Range
Dim arrRows()       As Variant
Dim arrTemp()       As Variant
Dim xFind           As Variant
Dim iCnt            As Long
Dim sMsg            As String

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="PYS"
Erase arrRows()
iCnt = 1
For Each c In Selection.Cells
    If Not c.ListObject Is Nothing Then
        If loSet Is Nothing Then
            Set loSet = c.ListObject
        Else
            If c.ListObject <> loSet Then
                'different table
                MsgBox "You have more than one table selected.", vbInformation, "ERROR!"
                ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="PYS"
                GoTo MyExit
            End If
        End If

        If iCnt = 1 Then
            ReDim arrRows(1 To iCnt)
            arrRows(iCnt) = c.Row - loSet.HeaderRowRange.Row
            iCnt = iCnt + 1
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
            xFind = 0
            xFind = WorksheetFunction.Match(c.Row - loSet.HeaderRowRange.Row, arrRows(), 0)
            If xFind = 0 Then
                ReDim Preserve arrRows(1 To iCnt)
                arrRows(iCnt) = c.Row - loSet.HeaderRowRange.Row
                iCnt = iCnt + 1
            End If
            Err.Clear
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If

    Else
        'a cell is not in a table
        MsgBox "Your selection is all or partially outside of a table.", vbInformation, "ERROR!"
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="PYS"
        GoTo MyExit
    End If
Next c

Call SortArray(arrRows())
sMsg = "Are you sure you want to delete " & UBound(arrRows) & " rows from from this table?"
If MsgBox(sMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "CONTINUE?") <> vbYes Then
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="PYS"
    Exit Sub
End If

For iCnt = UBound(arrRows) To LBound(arrRows) Step -1

    loSet.ListRows(arrRows(iCnt)).Delete
Next iCnt
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="PYS"
Exit Sub

MyExit:

End Sub



Sub SortArray(MyArray() As Variant)

Dim iStart          As Long
Dim iEnd            As Long
Dim iStep           As Long
Dim iMove           As Long
Dim vTemp           As Variant

iStart = LBound(MyArray)
iEnd = UBound(MyArray)
For iStep = iStart To iEnd - 1
    For iMove = iStep + 1 To iEnd
        If MyArray(iStep) > MyArray(iMove) Then
            vTemp = MyArray(iMove)
            MyArray(iMove) = MyArray(iStep)
            MyArray(iStep) = vTemp
        End If
    Next iMove
Next iStep

End Sub
```

By the way, I didn't come up with all of this myself; I piecemealed most of this code. :) Let me know if you need any more info or context. Thanks in advance!

[Here is the link to the budget workbook.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ZBMZsVFP5_U1M4MDZCeHB1WEE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: uploading an example workbook would be helpful.  A helpful suggestion is when working with protected sheets is to utilize a Workbook_Open event that will loop through sheets and protect them on open with the UserInterfaceOnly parameter set to true.  This allows vba to make changes to protected sheets without un-protecting and protecting the sheet each time, but still blocks users from editing.  Here is an example syntax `wbTCT.Sheets(i).Protect Password:="?CSandM!|", UserInterfaceOnly:=True` the loop is `For i = 1 to thisworkbook.sheets.count    Next i`

Comment: Please remove the "macros" tag, that is used for something else here at StackOverflow.

Comment: Just for your consideration I would like to note that Excel provides only very limited security (if any). Be aware that any security you choose is only as good as the software enforcing it. If you open an Excel file with Microsoft Excel, then all security mechanisms will be enforced as intended. But there are many other programs out there which do not do that. Also consider that not all computers run macros. With newer Excel versions most unsigned macros are actually blocked (unless you press a button to enable them).

Comment: Opening an Excel file with [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/) will even allow you to look at the VBA code without password protection (allowing a user to see the passwords in your code). All I am trying to say is that Excel provides only very limited security to you data if you allow someone to open it. If you really need to secure your data you might want to elect the usage of an SQL backend.

Comment: Thanks @Ralph, I wasn't really concerned with people viewing the password to unprotect the cells, as most average users don't know how to do that anyways. The password protection is only there to keep users from breaking the formulas, not to increase security. 

I also intend to write a simple user guide that includes that macros need to be enabled on this budget for it to work.

I realize that macros might not work for everyone, but that's the best that I can do.

Comment: @mongoose36 Thanks, I added a link to the excel file to the end of the post. I'll have to look into that Workbook_Open event once I figure out this obstacle! Probably much more efficient code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ActiveSheet.Cells(c.Row, 1).Value = "Deposits" ThenHere is the working DeleteRow sub

```
Sub DeleteRow()
'
' DeleteRow Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+D
'

    Dim loTtest         As ListObject
    Dim loSet           As ListObject
    Dim c               As Range
    Dim arrRows()       As Variant
    Dim arrTemp()       As Variant
    Dim xFind           As Variant
    Dim iCnt            As Long
    Dim sMsg            As String

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="PYS"
    Erase arrRows()
    iCnt = 1

    'This is the loop that I added before anything else to keep people from deleting the row with "Deposits"
    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(c.Row, 1).Value = "Deposits" Then
            MsgBox "Your Selection contains 'Deposits'!" & vbCrLf & _
                "The 'Deposits' row cannot be deleted!", vbExclamation
            GoTo MyExit
        End If
    Next

    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        If Not c.ListObject Is Nothing Then
            If loSet Is Nothing Then
                Set loSet = c.ListObject
            Else
                If c.ListObject <> loSet Then
                    'different table
                    MsgBox "You have more than one table selected.", vbInformation, "ERROR!"
                    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="PYS"
                    GoTo MyExit
                End If
            End If

            If iCnt = 1 Then
                ReDim arrRows(1 To iCnt)
                arrRows(iCnt) = c.Row - loSet.HeaderRowRange.Row
                iCnt = iCnt + 1
            Else
                On Error Resume Next
                xFind = 0
                xFind = WorksheetFunction.Match(c.Row - loSet.HeaderRowRange.Row, arrRows(), 0)
                If xFind = 0 Then
                    ReDim Preserve arrRows(1 To iCnt)
                    arrRows(iCnt) = c.Row - loSet.HeaderRowRange.Row
                    iCnt = iCnt + 1
                End If
                Err.Clear
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If

        Else
            'a cell is not in a table
            MsgBox "Your selection is all or partially outside of a table.", vbInformation, "ERROR!"
            ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="PYS"
            GoTo MyExit
        End If
    Next c

    Call SortArray(arrRows())
    sMsg = "Are you sure you want to delete " & UBound(arrRows) & " rows from from this table?"
    If MsgBox(sMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "CONTINUE?") <> vbYes Then
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="PYS"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For iCnt = UBound(arrRows) To LBound(arrRows) Step -1
        loSet.ListRows(arrRows(iCnt)).Delete
    Next iCnt
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="PYS"
    Exit Sub

MyExit:

End Sub
```

Comment: this is close, but the above code only protects the cell that contains "deposits", so if I were to select another cell in that row within the table, the macro will still run and delete the deposits row.

Additionally, the code should allow the deletion of deposits in another table within this sheet... just not the row of the table that contains "deposits" in column A.

Thanks again!

Comment: This is true...change `If c.Value = "Deposits" Then` to `If ActiveSheet.Cells(c.Row, 1).Value = "Deposits" Then`  I made the edit to the code above as well!